# cakephp redirect urls coming to localhost

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, cakephp

I have a cake php application dployed in my htdocs. I am not using a specific project folder and all cake files are inside the htdocs folder. I need to redirect a user to

```
localhost/page1
```

when the user visits

```
localhost
```

Pls advice me on how to do this?

Comment: What is `page1`? Is that the Cake root folder, or is this part of the Cake URL?

Comment: I have a page1Controller and a page1 view..my cake app is inside the htdocs. the folder structure is 
htdocs ->
app 
cake

like that 
basically I have not used a project folder and directly put cake contents inside my htdocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default route to your page1 controller. You can set this value in the Routes.php in the config folder. Set it to the following

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'page1', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I'm hoping `page1` is just an example you used. Make sure you're using proper naming standards when using cake.

Comment: Here is the section for the naming standards in the Cook Book: http://book.cakephp.org/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions

Comment: Hi guys tanx for ur valuable input.. yes I have added that router rule and am following the naming convention. When the user visits /localhost/ 
I need him to be directed to /localhost/pages/index
where I have implemented a static page using pagesController
and
I have added the following route
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'index'));
but when I navigate to / localhost/ 
it just lists down the files of the webroot
with Index of /app/webroot heading

any idea why?

Comment: mica & johnp thanx for the tips guys.. and when I resolve this I ll sure mark it ..SO is great...and helps people like me who r starting on cake..

Comment: HI thnx johnp.I found the solution..the initial problem was that I had some caching issue preventing the route changes functioning properly
got it done..thnx SO

Answer (score 1):

Look into app/config directory. There is a route.php. You can use/define routes in this file. 
Read the [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration) about routes.